# Customer email header that doesn't get stripped

Tags: email, header, smtp, correlation

We need to pass some data in emails that can be used for tracking and correlation, we were looking at using a custom header or a token in the subject/body.

Does anyone know of an email header that can be used that will not be removed by email servers? I know you can add X- headers to specify custom content but it seems you can never be sure they won't survive either the server stripping them or being removed when the email is forwarded.

The token option also doesn't seem ideal as it can easily be removed by the user, are there any other better techniques?

Thanks for your time

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A server should not be stripping X- headers (as long as they are correctly formatted, anyway), unless perhaps you happen to pick a name for that X- header that the server uses for its own purposes. But there is no header that *cannot* be stripped or altered by a server or user. A proper forward operation should preserve the headers, and an improper forward isn't guaranteed to retain any headers.

A header is probably the best method, both because most users won't be aware that headers besides "From", "To", and "Subject" even exist and because that's really the place for such metadata. Encoding it in the Message-Id header might be slightly more robust than in an X- header. Or if it's very short, you could encode it in the subject line as a "ticket number" or the like.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the reply, I think we'll go with some sort of combination of the above so at least there's a chance of keeping the token available

Comment: Bringing to topic back from the dead:
has anyone figured out which header (or reference) can survive reply by Gmail and MS-Outlook
If yes, any thoughts about future-proofing this?